# Are there guidelines for creating panel icons?

Tags: gnome-panel, development

I'm looking to submit a patch to a project who's panel icon is larger than the other icons, specifically it is the full height of the panel, whereas the others have a few pixels of space above and below, and I'd like to shrink the icon so that it's consistent with the others. Does Canonical have any guidelines on the size of these icons, or is it left up to the developers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canonical has guidelines for [application indicators](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators), but more specifically you would be looking for a guideline for the gnome-panel and to my knowledge, there probably is not one specifically, though there may be something about it in the [GNOME HIG](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flibrary.gnome.org%2Fdevel%2Fhig-book%2F&ei=IyHwTIzGMpO8sQOC-sTVCw&usg=AFQjCNH0cAjUIRrjhPpmaB5AUeYTU3zAyw&sig2=neeeBsuRbvn9-ZecfWc5kA).